# How do I explicitly see that the Ultrapower map is the identity below its critical point?

Tags: set-theory, large-cardinals

I apologize in advance for how basic this question is...

Let $j:V\rightarrow V/U$ be the ultrapower map where U is an ultrafilter on a set S, and $j(x)=[c_x]$.  Now, let $f\in j(0)$.  Then $f$ is undefined almost everywhere on S, but we're assuming $f$ is a function defined on all of S, so we conclude no such $f$ exists, and so $j(0)=0$.  Okay, that I get.  Now look at $j(1)$.  By the same argument, $f\in j(1)$ iff $f=\emptyset$ a.e.  So now my issue; this isn't unique!  As long as it's 0 almost everywhere, I can give $f$ random values elsewhere.  And in any case, it's a function on S, not $\{\emptyset\}$.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $j$ is an elementary embedding, then it is 1-1, this is the definition of an embedding.

The critical point is the first ordinal such that $j(\kappa)\neq\kappa$. Suppose $\alpha=j(\kappa)<\kappa$ then what would $j(\alpha)$ be? It cannot be $\alpha$ because $j$ is 1-1. So you have to have $j(\kappa)>\kappa$.

So if $\kappa$ is the smallest one that moves, $j(\alpha)=\alpha$ for every ordinal below $\kappa$ and thus it is the identity map.

Comment: Thank you, but I'm wondering how you can see $j(1)=1$ directly.  I know it's true because it's below the critical point, but I should be able to see this by explicit construction.

Comment: @King Louis XIV: This is by elementarity. The empty set is absolute so $j(0)=0$ and being the successor of $\alpha$ is definable from $\alpha$. So $j(1)=1$.

Comment: Again a good answer, and the simplest answer, but I'd like to see it explicitly.

Comment: If $[f]\in_U j(1)$, then $f(i)\in 1$ for $U$-a.e. $i$, which means that $f(i)=0$ for $U$-a.e. $i$, and so $f=_U c_0$ which means $[f]_U=[c_0]=j(0)$, and so $j(1)=\{j(0)\}=\{0\}=1$.